# How can I split a.csv file in Progress4GL if it exceeds 1000000 lines

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

In my program I am outputting a .csv file which exceeds 1000000 lines. Currently after the file is exported, I am splitting the file from linux using the below commands. However, I would like to know if we can split the files using a progress code. If so, could someone plese let me know on how to do it.

Below is the linux command I use manually.

```
ls -l xa*
split -1000000 filename.csv
mv xaa filename-01.csv
mv xab filename-02.csv
```

Comment: Of course you can but you should post some code outputting the file to help us help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any code to work with I invented some code outputting to different files. You will have to work with `OUTPUT TO` and set new filenames.

This example will output 1050 lines split in files of 100 lines each.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE iLinesToOutput AS INTEGER NO-UNDO INIT 1050.
DEFINE VARIABLE iSplitAt       AS INTEGER NO-UNDO INIT  100.

DEFINE VARIABLE iLine AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iFile AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iOpen AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE STREAM str.

DO iLine = 1 TO iLinesToOutput:
    
    // Open a new stream/file    
    IF (iLine - 1 ) MOD iSplitAt = 0 THEN DO:
        iFile = iFile + 1.
        cFile  = "c:\temp\file-" + STRING(iFile, "999") + ".txt".
        OUTPUT STREAM str TO VALUE(cFile).
        EXPORT STREAM str DELIMITER "," "Customer ID" "Order Number" "Contact" "Count"
    END.
    
    // Output some data
    PUT STREAM str UNFORMATTED "Line " iLine SKIP.
    
    // Close the stream/file 
    IF iLine MOD iSplitAt = 0 THEN DO:
        OUTPUT STREAM str CLOSE.
    END.
    
END.

/* Close last file if not exactly right number of lines */
/* This could also be checked but close twice doesn't really matter */
OUTPUT STREAM str CLOSE.
```

Comment: FWIW I would like to suggest using portable sample file names rather than Windows specific names with stuff like "C:" and unescaped "\" embedded in them ;)

Comment: @TomBascom Thats a valid remark

Comment: Since you are spending two comment lines on how you can close a stream that has already been closed, you can move the close before the open and save an extra modulo calculation per line :-)

Comment: @StefanDrissen Nice code golf move there!

Comment: Thanks Jensd for the answer. What needs to be done if need the header to be copied for all the split files.

Comment: @VarunSulabha How do you add the header now? You could `PUT/EXPORT` something after the `OPEN` statement

Comment: This is my header statement.

'DEFINE NEW SHARED STREAM sErr.    
OUTPUT STREAM sErr TO /export/home/vks/vks-Err.csv.
EXPORT STREAM sErr DELIMITER ","
                              "Customer ID"
                              "Order Number"
                              "Contact"
                              "Count".'

How can I add the same header for the split files automatically?

Comment: Added the header...